# Building the best proxy for an economic indicator

Tags: references, economics

I've been asked to help people from the Economics Department with an index A which is a geographically restricted GDP. This index was expensive to calculate, so they have data on it only for 1993-1999 and 2004-2012.

They have a proxy B which is basically a linear model made from of a different dataset with many predictors but few samples of each. The proxy follows the up and down trends of the index.

How can they construct a better proxy with the data they have?

My ideas boil down to models other than averaging, and comparing how well their proxies follow the trends of the index. Maybe there are better approaches. I am confused a bit because we are not trying to predict the index A but rather to construct a good proxy B. Where can I read about such problems?

Comment: What is a proxy but a prediction that is sufficiently close?

Comment: A proxy variable differs from the variable you aim to measure, yet they are expected to exhibit a strong correlation. A prediction represents a value that your model asserts to be sufficiently close to the actual value you seek to forecast.

Comment: Correlation is one way to measure how close the predictions are to the true values.

Comment: But how can you talk about predictions when the predictors do no coincide? I have a set of variables that serves to construct an index and I have to use a different set of variables to construct something that follows the trend.

Comment: The vagueness is awkward here. Perhaps $A$ is healthcare spending in California; perhaps the available data $B_1,B_2,B_3$ are California GDP, US GDP, and US healthcare spending; perhaps the proxies so far are based on regressions of $\ln A = q+ r\ln B_1-s\ln B_2+t\ln B_3$. That would be a lot easier to discuss, and it’s probably not hard to provide the actual example in similar detail.

Comment: Let's see if this helps: A is a geographic version of GDP, it's basically the same as GDP but geographically restricted. In particular is measured in currency. B is an index constructed from a wide variety of economic indicators such as energy consumption in the industrial sector or number of tourists arriving to the city in a period of time. The bottom line is that B is not a prediction of A, is a different indicator that is supposed to serve to predict trends in A. Is that clearer?

Comment: So why don’t close predictions count as a proxy?

Comment: @hamath, that’s clearer but it’s worth editing the post with that information. In particular, “weighted average” suggests homogeneous units as in my example; it’s a misleading description for physical inputs in a variety of units all distinct from the currency output. Perhaps “linear model” would describe the current proxy better.

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, in here I think there are two main ways to intend a proxy Y for indicator X:

1. Y can be a quantity correlated with X "enough" so that we can infer X behaviour by that. An example is what you have in environmental epidemiology: when we study the effect of air pollution on a health outcome (e.g. death) we need to assign a value of exposure to every subject in our study. Obtaining personal exposure measurement can be very costly, as you need to equip every subject with a sensor for a specific period of time and it is unfeasible for large studies (>1000 people). Most often, residential outdoor air pollution exposure is used in place of the personal measurements. Outdoor air pollution measurement are more convenient because we can use a variety of tools to obtain it (e.g. national ground monitors, satellites data and so on). Of course, outdoor pollution cannot substitute fully personal measurements, but they have worked pretty well so far and many studies found decent consistencies between them.

So, the Y from point 1) is what I would call a (more or less) *clearly defined proxy* in this case. You can give a name to the proxy and this name reflects a quantity that we (more or less) can clearly define.

2. When an intuitive measure as from point 1) is not available or you cannot find one for now, what you can do is to put together a bunch other data Z (i.e. you can use several Zs) that you assume related with X and build a statistical model that predicts X. This seems to be your case.
   Now, the next good question might be: *do I need this model to be interpretable or all I care is to build something that predicts X as good as posssible?*
   Here you need to answer the question. If you need to be able to interpret the relationships between each Z and X, then probably something like a "linear model" can suit you well. However, this might not suit well your data that can have non-linear relationships, but that's a another problem. In this case I would also consider drawing a DAG (directed acyclic graph) to define the relationship between your Zs and X. This can be very useful sometimes.
   However, if you don't care about interpretation of Z, then there is a lot of literature on all sort of prediction models, from little interpretability to "black boxes" (models with very good predictive characteristics but little to no interpretability). Consider that in general, any model you decide to define will require you to validate it (there are several methods, e.g. cross-validation) that will make the model strong to potential "biases" within your data.

I didn't add any reference because the question is too broad in the way it is asked, so I just wanted to help to clarify things for you.

Comment: Shorter version: Proxies which are *more convenient* and *clearly defined* may be preferable to *more predictive* combinations of data. Eg a good proxy for an individual’s exposure to pollution is the outdoor air pollution.

Comment: That's a very nice reply @jmarkov, thank you so much. I would like to make a follow-up question: my hunch is that your point 1 is what may work in my case. Reading your reply I come to think that my question boils down to this: the people from Economics cooked up a proxy Y for variable X. Somehow I have to come up with a proxy W for variable X (with the same dataset as Y). Bottom line question: what are some techniques (or references) on how to construct such a W and how do I measure which one correlates better to X?

Comment: Hi @hamath, I am glad you found this answer useful. Well, you find yourself in situation 2) of my answer. This means you need to develop a predictive model. In general, This is not straightfoward and there is not clear answer. I imagine you want the model to be somewhat interpretable in terms of the variable you include. Maybe you can start building a linear model and include some of the Z variables (the predictors) non linearly to see how your $R^2$ changes. However, in general I recommend you to look into something like "how to build a predictive model in econometrics" or similar.

Comment: Another example, a predictive model could also be a machine learning model if you don't need interpretability! I recommend you also speak with someone who has experience in constructing models like that in your field. It can be difficult to do it on your own and you can come up with something misleading.